# Number of observations in a node in XGBoost

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I understand how the cover is calculated in XGBoost, the sum hessian at that node. For the root node of tree 1 for binary logistic, it becomes n(.5)(1-.5) with base score as 0.5. The cover at root node for tree 1 is $\sum{(p(1-p))}$ where p is the predicted probabilities from the first tree.

What I need is the exact number of observations at each node. Cover "is a metric to measure the number of observations affected by the split"; I need to translate this to the exact number for any given node.

Also, min_child_weight says what is the minimum sum of instance weight needed in a child. So min_child_weight is the minimum 'Cover' in the tree? Correct me if I am wrong.